# WPF load new usercontrol within same window

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window that I want replaced with another user control on a button click instead of a new window with `.Show()`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Window has a Grid 'LayoutRoot' with the currrent Window contents within it, you can change the contents in code-behind as follows:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Clear()
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new MyUserControl());
```

Where MyUserControl is your new UserControl.

Comment: What if I cannot clear all the children? How do I remove one specific row,column pair?

Comment: You should probably start a new question for this, and include you XAML so that we can understand exactly what you want to remove.